# LIMIT 0,5 is making Query run 350 times SLOWER

Tags: mysql, database

The following MySQL query completes in under **0.02 seconds**:

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    `Table1`
 WHERE
    `col1`     = '43532' AND
    `col2`     = 'N'
 ORDER BY col3 DESC
```

However, if I add `LIMIT 0, 5` at the end of it, it completes in over **7 seconds**:

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    `Table1`
 WHERE
    `col1`     = '43532' AND
    `col2`     = 'N'
 ORDER BY col3 DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 5
```

This is happening even when the query returns an empty result set.

Why is the addition of `LIMIT 0, 5` causing this simple query to be 350 times slower?  I need to be able to limit the results for pagination reasons, so how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

WITHOUT LIMIT, `EXPLAIN` says:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len   ref     rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      Table1  ref     col1,col2       col1    5         const   2441  Using where; Using filesort
```

WITH LIMIT, `EXPLAIN` says:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key   key_len   ref   rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      Table1  index   col1,col2       col3  5         NULL  1050  Using where
```

Comment: @ckruse:  Please see my edit above.

Comment: This may be helpful, how to optimize queries: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm

Comment: Is that the explain plain for both queries? Maybe the LIMIT forces MySQL in using another key.

Comment: Can you add "select SQL_NO_CACHE" to make sure you are getting true timing results and a "SHOW INDEX FROM <tablename>" may be good too. Could you also EXPLAIN both queries?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Please see new EDIT above for the 2 different EXPLAIN's I get for each query (with/without LIMIT 0,5).

Comment: @Adrian Cornish:  SQL_NO_CACHE made no difference.  SHOW INDEX FROM Table1 listed several indexed columns individually, including ALL columns contained in the query (col1, col2, and col3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the limit causes MySQL to order the query first, forcing it to order the whole set, and then filter it, not using indexes.

There are directives to tell MySQL which index to use, but it may be better to create a combined index on col1, col2 and col3. MySQL should use that index for filtering and sorting. You should experiment to see whether the query is faster if col3 is the first or the last column in that index.

Answer (score 0):

Limit start,margin depends on the calculation of the DB engine.
For pagination don't hit the DB for every 5 rows, best would be, u bring 500 records to 
front end, and then cater there via javascript, for every next 500 records hit the DB which will be acceptable..

Comment: But why would it make the Query 350 times slower, even on an empty result set?  It seems like something else is going on...

Comment: It first fetches the records and then, extract the rows needed, and insert into the temp_table and then extracts the desired rows from the temp_table...